# I cannot understand this programming style

Tags: c#, boolean, variable-assignment

Can someone explain to me what this line of code means and whether it is good practice?

It seems to me that it is trying to assign one or another value to a boolean, but it is not clear.

```
   myBoolVar = isC || isP || isX;
```

Comment: This is not programming "style", it is just "programming", which you need to learn about, before wasting your own time and ours, with ridiculously elementary questions like these.

Comment: Here, get an upvote. It’s a basic question but it’s an entirely valid one. Those downvoters need a heavy dose of caffeine and humility.

Comment: @Konrad - seconded. Not a well phrased question, but it's entirely valid

Comment: @KonradRudolph Asking whether one trivial line of code is "good practice", with no explanation of why you think it might or might not be, is a valid question?! Seriously?! Is "is `i = 1;` good practice?" a valid question in your opinion?

Comment: @David The real question here was that the OP didn’t understand the code. As a follow-up, asking whether it’s good (and, by implication, common) style seems reasonable.

Comment: George Boole approves of the logic of this statement.  He's however quite unpleased about the identifier name choices.

Comment: @BrianAgnew. I deleted the comment, though I don't believe this question is a real one. Everyone who learn C# should know what this means or wait with the questions to the next chapter.

Comment: +1 It's a very basic question but seems entirely legitimate. No need to get all het up about it.

Comment: I've removed my downvote in light of the fact we appear to have a >15k user who doesn't know what this does either.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Let's try to be nicer to the beginners, okay? We all start somewhere.

Comment: @thedayturns Exactly, like a) a book, b) a class, c) an online tutorial.

Answer (score 14):

[The `||` operator represents a conditional OR.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.80).aspx)

myBoolVar will be true if any of isC, isP, or isX is true.

It is similar to the [| operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kxszd0kx(v=vs.80).aspx) between boolean operands *except that if the left-hand-side evaluates to true, the right-hand-side will not be evaluated*.

As to whether it's good practise, consider a more verbose semantic equivalent:-

```
bool myBoolVar;

if (isC)
{
  myBoolVar = true;
}
else if (isP)
{
  myBoolVar = true;
}
else if (isX)
{
  myBoolVar = true;
}
```

In particular, consider which one you would prefer to maintain. For the most part, I would expect that folks consider the terser `myBoolVar = isC || isP || isX;` to be more readable.

I see from the comments below that you make an argument about programming being about simplicity and not about "showing off". I agree that programmers often try to compact or deliberately obfuscate code for their own satisfaction - often to the detriment of the project. This is probably **not** one of those cases. I might name the variables more clearly and I might encapsulate it behind an appropriately-named property, but I'd definitely use the `a || b || c` construction over something more verbose.

If you feel you have a clearer way to express it, share it with us and we can discuss it.

Comment: It is worth noting that `||` is "logical or" while `|` is "binary or". They only get the same result if both operands are `bool` values.

Comment: Why throw the bitwise OR operator into the mix? The OP obviously has barely any idea what he'd doing in the first place. Why confuse him any more? Booleans --> logical OR. Integer bitmasking --> bitwise OR.

Comment: @MagnusHoff and Jonathon, `|` between boolean operands is not binary or bitwise. It is a boolean operator with full evaluation.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: I don't mean to be rude, but a) the | operator is a logical operator as well as a bitwise one, b) the short-circuiting behaviour of the || operator is fundamental to its usage, c) if you're so angry about the OP wasting your time, why are you commenting?

Comment: Who said I was angry? I suggested that he go read, and learn instead of wasting his own time too. I understand the short-circuit behavior of || and in my experience, I've never seen | used for "full evaluation" of boolean expressions, although I understand it works like that. I was suggesting we keep it simple for the OP who is obviously on chapter 1.

Comment: @MagnusHoff that is not correct. "Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands. For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the result is false if and only if both its operands are false." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx

Comment: @fsimonazzi Okay, a slight mixup of nomenclature. `|` is apparently called "The `|` operator". My point still stands, though: Only if both operands are boolean can you be sure that the only difference between `||` and `|` is the short-circuiting. My comment is meant to elaborate on the claim that "It is similar to the | operator". Yes, it is similar, but it is worth noting that it *can* produce different results in addition to different side-effects. Keep in mind that the OP does not specify the types of all the variables. I hope this clears things up :)

Answer (score 5):

This is the conditional `OR`. The values of `isC` and `isP` and `isX` are `OR`-ed together.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

All you need to do is Read The Fine Manual.

Comment: Non word characters are difficult to search for - 'Your search - || - did not match any documents.'

Comment: I didn't say "Google it", I said "RTFM"... So if you read a proper book on C#, you learn how to use this. How come so many people just dive into programming without reading proper textbooks??

Answer (score 3):

the `||` operator simply means OR. So in pseudocode you might say

```
myBoolVal = isC OR isP OR isX
```

What this does in plain english...

"If isC is true, or isP is true, or isX is true, then myBoolVal is true, otherwise, myBoolVal is false"

Answer (score 2):

Returns true if any of them has `true` value

```
bool myBoolVar = false;
if( isC == true || isP == true || isX == true)
{
    myBoolVar = true;
}
```

Comment: == true is superfluous when comparing booleans.

Comment: I think he did that intentionally to make a blindingly obvious answer to a blindingly obvious question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart you are correct, i did it intentionally to make it as clear as possible

Comment: +1 for being abundantly clear. This is good pedagogical style.

Answer (score 1):

It is [conditional OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

It means Any of the variable from `isC, isP, isX` is `True` then `myBoolVar` is `True`

That is:

```
myBoolVar = if(isC == true) || if(isP == true) || if(isX == true)
```

Comment: I love how you use the `||` operator anyways in your example anyways. I would suggest breaking it into three statements.